ReactNative android
In the ReactNative project, I deleted the Android folder and copied another Android project that could run normally. Gradle compilation kept reporting errors
e: /Users/oliver/Desktop/Android/RpaStudio/android/app/src/main/java/com/ii/rpa/bot/reactnative/MainActivity.kt: (3, 12): Unresolved reference: facebook
version info:
ReactNative: 0.73.6
JAVA: 1.8
ReactNative/android/build.gradle:
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.10"

ReactNative/android/app/build.gradle:
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-android:0.73.6"
implementation "com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.73.6"
implementation "com.facebook.react:hermes-android:0.73.6" 

I just want to create a new ReactNative project and include my previous Android project, which can run normally. This is my ultimate goal.
使用Android Studio先编译了android是可以正常运行的，但是我添加了ReactNative相关的依赖、MainActivity.kt、MainApplication.kt、修改了AndroidManifest.xml
